# Cannot go to the site columns page, got this error: Field type CrossSiteLookup is not installed properly

Tags: 2010, site-column

I am using sp2010. When I go to the site columns page of the site below (http://myCompany.com/sites/archive/_layouts/mngfield.aspx) I got this error:

Field type CrossSiteLookup is not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete this field.

I did empty already the recycle bin.

What can I do to fix this?

**UPDATE**
Someone told me, this sharepoint portal was before sp2007. There was a third party wsp installed which installed this custom field type "CrossSiteLookup". The sharepoint portal is migrated from sp2007 to sp2010, but the wsp isnt migrated. So at this moment the custom field type is not available. There is a column which is refered to this custom field type. I try to remove it in powershell but get the same error.

Do I need to deploy this custom field type to make it possible to remove the column which is refered to this custom field type?

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by missing WSP (solution file), containing custom field type on your target SharePoint installation. You could try installing the WSP (old solution) which contains the custom field type, and then you remove it from site columns via GUi

if you fail to find WSP, try to remove this custom field type via APIs or PowerShell for e.g here is a small script which removes such field : http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/RemoveDelete-a-fieldcolumn-46e65f5b

Direct query to SQL databases is **not** recommended.

Answer (score 0):

instead of powershell use the UI, goto the list -> list settings -> click on the column and delete

Comment: I dont know which list is using this field type. I have created a powershell script which loops into all lists to find a column from this type. 0 results. I check also the sub websites. I know now which index the column is in powershell.  $fields = $web.Fields $fields[443] . Can I remove this field with powsershell from web?

Comment: yes you can remove the field from powershell, i presume that the field is never used now? it shouldnt break the list as its a field

Answer (score 0):

I have removed this column from sql. It was available in the "ContentTypes" table.

Answer (score 0):

You said you created a powershell script to iterate over the columns in the list. I suggest you modify this script to also iterate over all the Content Types in the lists and remove it if found. Then iterate over all the site level fields that could reference this type and remove them too.
As you have 3 levels where it could be implemented you probably need to clear all of them.

Comment: The script does it all :) http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/RemoveDelete-a-fieldcolumn-46e65f5b